# jqgrid checkbox selectable even when beforeSelectRow returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In jqgrid with multiselect enabled, even when the beforeSelectRow returns false, the checkbox remains checkable. Is it a bug and if so is there a workaround for this.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Usecase here:
http://jsfiddle.net/erduT/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/erduT/2/

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not exactly a bug, beforeSelectRow in this case is disabling the selection of the **row**, not the selection of the checkbox. Which is evident in your fiddle since the row itself does not remain highlighted. So in your beforeSelectRow function you are going to have to disable any other UI elements yourself.

Ex.

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
    $('#jqg_grid_' + rowid).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    return false;
},
```

For working with the Select All/None checkbox you can use the **onSelectAll** event.

> Params: aRowids,status
>
> This event fires when multiselect option is
>   true and you click on the header checkbox.
>
> **aRowids** - array of the selected rows (rowid's).
>
> **status** - boolean variable determining the status of the header check box - true if checked, false if not checked.
>
> *Note that the aRowids alway contain the ids when header checkbox is checked or unchecked.*

Ex.

```
onSelectAll: function(aRowids,status) {
     if (status) {
          $.each(aRowids, function(i, rowid) {
               $('#jqg_grid_' + rowid).attr("disabled", "disabled");
          });
     }
},
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. apart from that I also need to handle somehow the selectAll/unselectAll on the top row of the table as well in this case itseems.